# Table View Displays Below Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My issue is that the last cell in my TableView is below the screen view and to see it you must scroll up and hold your position. At a neutral position where you dont scroll up, you cant see the last cell. Everything seemed fine until i changed the size of the cells. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

//MARK : Properties
var tableView = UITableView()
var items: [String] = ["Age", "Gender", "Smoking Hx", "Occup. -Ag", "Family Hx", "Chronic Lung Disease Radiology", "Chronic Lung Disease Hx", "Nodule Border", "Nodule Location", "Satellite Lesions", "Nodule Pattern Cavity", "Nodule Size"]
var navigationBar = NavigationBar()
var gender = GenderView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create TableView
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height * 0.097, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height);
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)



    //Create Navigation Bar with custom class
    self.navigationBar = NavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height * 0.097))
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    //Cell wont turn grey when selected
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

 return self.view.bounds.height * 0.095

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")


}


}
```

The only thing i could think of causing this issue is that instead of me creating a navigation bar, i created a "navigationBar" using a custom UIView() class. I then start the table view at the bottom of the navigation bar. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the NavigationBar.swift:

```
class NavigationBar: UIView {

var navigationBar = UIView()
var header = UILabel()
var lineBorder = UIView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.frame = frame
    setUpView()
}

func setUpView(){


    //Create Navigation Bar
    navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.addSubview(navigationBar)

    //Create Line Border
    lineBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.height, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height * 0.005)
    lineBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.addSubview(lineBorder)


    header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)
    header.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)
    header.text = "Nodule Risk Calculator"
    //header.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.addSubview(header)
    header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    header.centerHorizontallyTo(navigationBar, padding: 0)
    header.centerVerticallyTo(navigationBar, padding: 9)

}


func hide(){
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height * 0.097, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height);
```

has problem. The origin.y is not 0, and you still feed the whole height. So the table view will have some area below the screen

Try this:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height * 0.097, self.view.bounds.width, 
                             self.view.bounds.height - self.view.bounds.height * 0.097);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationBar = NavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height * 0.097))
self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

var yAxis : Float = self.navigationBar.frame.height
var tblHeight : Float = self.view.bounds.height - yAxis

tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yAxis, self.view.bounds.width, tblHeight)
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```